# Does Dovecot make Foxmail / Thunderbird / Outlook to receive duplicated email?

Tags: email, dovecot, outlook, mailbox, thunderbird

I've built a **`Postfix(2.10.1-7.el7.x64.rpm) + Dovecot(2.3.11-build)`** mail server for my host. It functions well for me at the very beginning.

After using for a while, I kept receiving duplicated mails from my server. I try to figure it out where did they come from. But I finally found they share the same **`MESSAGE-ID`**, which is identified by receiving mails. I try to use different email client, Foxmail/Thunderbird/Outlook, but it results the same.

I try to figout it out how they functioned. And I found out when I receiving a mail, which comes from a persistent connection, it would be very easily to duplicate a mail if I pulled it from mail server by my own at the same time.

This does not make sense, does anybody knows how to config the dovecot server to avoid the duplication of mails from client? It would be great helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain that is the postfix version you are using in 2020?

Comment: You probably want to investigate logs about where the duplication occurred. *grep* for the message ID and and then look at preceding/following messages or those sharing postfix or dovecot IDs (did postfix already receive the message twice? was it submitted to dovecot twice? did a postfix sieve script duplicate the message?)

Comment: I've check the mailbox, the mail with the same message-id only got one, and there 're no double mail from postfix. And the log from postfix only have one record.

Comment: nope, definitely imap

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for that I am not familiar with postfix and dovecot, I found an article that may be helpful to you.  [Prevent duplicate Drafts, Junk, Sent, Trash folders in Dovecot](https://www.webdesignblog.asia/web-design/hosting/prevent-duplicate-drafts-junk-sent-trash-folders-dovecot/#sthash.1bSGNG6O.dpbs)